# Whether 'rope pull' is appropriate

Tags: verbs

I am looking for a word that describes the struggle between two sides (politicians and para-military groups) aiming for state control.
Can I refer to it as *rope pull*?
I want to really emphasize the battle of the two sides being involved.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably referring to a ***[tug of war](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rope+pulling)*** which is :

> - (Games) ***A contest of strength*** in which two teams tug on opposite ends of a rope, each trying to pull the other across a dividing line.

and figuratively:

> - ***A struggle for supremacy***: a political tug of war between those in favor of the proposal and those against it.

(AHD)

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say thank you again, is that right? It's my first time here, so I am not accustomed to the unspoken laws yet.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can build noun chains in which all except the last are used as modifiers.  E.g. "valve spring retainer clip" is a clip.  The other nouns are adjectived.